# Better type annotations for function props with flow

Tags: reactjs, redux, flowtype

I have the following type definition for a component:

```
type Props = {
  address: {
    addressIndex: number,
    entryState: string
  },
  changeEntryState: Function,
  change: Function,
  untouch: Function,
  clearApplicantFields: Function
};
```

Function is very generic, is there anything I can do to make this more specific?

They are all redux actions and `change` and `untouch` come from `redux-form`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example

```
changeEntryState: (val: string) => number
```

or

```
changeEntryState: (str: string, bool?: boolean, ...nums: Array<number>) => void
```